# Extracting values and units from character column to multiple new columns (using extract in R:dplyr?)

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, extract

I have looked through many different previous questions but not come up with one that is solving my problem

I have a very messy and irregular character column in a data frame that looks like this:
cost$k1:

```
 "33p/kWh”
 "40p/kWh on bp pulse50 units. 50p/kWh on bp pulse150 units."                                                                                                                    
 "42p/kWh”
 "Free"                                                                                                                                                                          
 "30p/kWh ( min £1.50 )”
 "42p/kWh”
 "Polar members: 12p/kWh”
 "Polar Subscription - 27p/kWh Polar Free Membership - 42p/kWh Contactless - 42p/kWh"                                                                                            
 "47p/kWh”
 "47p/kWh”
 "25p/kWh”
 "25p/kWh”
 "50kW: 43p/kWh”
```

I need to try and take up to 4 of the prices (including the units) and put them into new columns for example:

```
 cost$k2[2] would be "40p/kWh"
 cost$k3[2] would be "50p/kWh" 
 cost$k2[8] would be "27p/kWh"
 cost$k3[8] would be "42p/kWh" 
 cost$k4[8] would be "42p/kWh"
```

Looking around has suggested that dplyr::extract() should be ideal, but I am having problems getting it to work.

Three examples which I have just spent too long reordering and moving around are….

```
cost %>% extract(k1,c("k2","k3","k4"),"([0-9]+p/kWh)-([0-9]+p/kWh)-([0-9]+p/kWh)",remove=FALSE)
```

Gives no results

```
cost %>%  extract(k1,"([[0-9]+]p/kWh)",remove=FALSE)
```

just gets me the first set of numbers and not the units, or even the correct units

```
cost %>%  extract(k1,into = c("k2","k3","k4"),regex="([0-9]+p/kWh)*([0-9]+p/kWh)*([[0-9]+p/kWh)",remove=FALSE)
```

Gets me the numbers and units where there is one cost but only writes this this to column k4 (in row 4 it gets me the 40p/kWh but not the 50p/kWh

Any ideas?

Data here

```
structure(list(ID = c(194597L, 194510L, 193430L, 191632L, 190347L, 
190056L, 189724L, 189630L, 189350L, 189349L, 188842L, 188841L, 
188046L, 176130L, 175867L, 175683L, 175682L, 175526L, 175354L, 
175323L, 175034L, 174985L, 173800L, 173795L, 173794L, 173713L, 
173668L, 173518L, 173027L, 173026L, 173025L, 173018L, 172194L, 
172008L, 171158L, 171137L, 171136L, 170768L, 170767L, 170764L, 
170763L, 170701L, 170372L, 170368L, 170366L, 170365L, 170364L, 
170362L, 170359L, 170356L), k1 = c("20p/kWh", "25p/kWhContactless Card ", 
"33p/kWh; other tariffs available", "40p/kWh on bp pulse50 units. 50p/kWh on bp pulse150 units.", 
"42p/kWh; other tariffs available", "33p/kWh; other tariffs available", 
"35p/kWh; other tariffs available", "16p/kWh; other tariffs available", 
"Free", "42p/kWh; other tariffs available", "26p/kWh; other tariffs available", 
"26p/kWh; other tariffs available", "35p/kWh. Overstay £10.00/hour after 90 mins; other tariffs available", 
"30p/kWh ( min £1.50 ); other tariffs available. Parking fees apply", 
"33p/kWh; other tariffs available", "33p/kWh; other tariffs available", 
"33p/kWh; other tariffs available", "42p/kWh; other tariffs available", 
"42p/kWh; other tariffs available", "47p/kWh; other tariffs available", 
"42p/kWh; other tariffs available", "Polar members: 12p/kWh; instant: 18p/kWh (£1.20 min payment)", 
"Polar Subscription - 27p/kWh Polar Free Membership - 42p/kWh Contactless - 42p/kWh", 
"47p/kWh; other tariffs available", "47p/kWh; other tariffs available", 
"25p/kWh; other tariffs available", "25p/kWh; other tariffs available", 
"50kW: 43p/kWh; 150kW: 42p/kWh; other tariffs available", "Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", 
"Polar members: 12p/kWh; instant: 18p/kWh (£1.20 min payment)", 
"Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", "25p/kWh; other tariffs available", 
"Polar members: 12p/kWh; instant: 18p/kWh (£1.20 min payment)", 
"Polar members: 12p/kWh; instant: 18p/kWh (£1.20 min payment)", 
"30p/kWh Contactless; Overstay £10/hour after 90 minutes; Other tariffs available", 
"Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", "Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", 
"Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", "Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", 
"Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", "Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", 
"40p - 20p/kWh", "Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", 
"Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", "Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", 
"Rapids Polar Card 15p/kWh, Contactless 20p/kWh", "40p - 20p/kWh", 
"40p - 20p/kWh", "40p - 20p/kWh", "Polar Plus 20p/kWh Polar Instant 35p/kWh Contactless 40p/kWh £1.50 connection charge"
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001e772333ba0>)
```

Comment: Can you share your dataframe with `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

With `str_extract_all`:

```r
str_extract_all(df$k1, '\\b\\d+p/kWh')
# [[1]]
# [1] "33p/kWh"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "40p/kWh" "50p/kWh"
```

Or in a dataframe:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(col = str_extract_all(k1, '\\b\\d+p/kWh')) %>% 
  unnest_wider(col, names_sep = "")

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  k1                                                         col1    col2   
  <chr>                                                      <chr>   <chr>  
1 33p/kWh                                                    33p/kWh NA     
2 40p/kWh on bp pulse50 units. 50p/kWh on bp pulse150 units. 40p/kWh 50p/kWh
```

data

```r
df = data.frame(k1 = c("33p/kWh",
 "40p/kWh on bp pulse50 units. 50p/kWh on bp pulse150 units."))
```

Comment: That's great - thanks -that gets me a good chunk of the way!
I have put some more of the data up there now in case you fancy  finishing off the problem! I can probably work on a cludgey solution from here myself though.

The main issue is that by using the word boundary to whitespace approach it is picking up a lot of other figures e.g.  "10.00/hour"  "1.50;" or even addition characters e.g. "30p/kWh;min"

Comment: Therefore I was hoping to define something which specifically grabbed by the unit definition "p/kWh" (and preferably copied the units into the new columns rather than just the figures before hand so that it is easy to check that they are all the correct figures

Comment: See my edit. You can indeed then replace \\S* by p/Kwh

Comment: Actually I have now got the mixed rgex to work with '\\b\\d+p/kWh'
the combination of wildcards and text (incl forward slash) had been causing me problems

Thanks very much indeed.....